# Javascript loading only after postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Sorry if this question may be simple, but I can't seem to find an answer, and it's just becoming more and more frustrating.

So, I'm on a master page and on this master page is a nifty jQuery method to 'fade' images.

Of course, the first time I load the page it blows up, but *only if I'm referencing it locally*.

However, I know the path to the file is correct (or if it's not it's sure fooling me) because if I enable any sort of postback (such as logging in), when the page refreshes, the jQuery loads without incident.

On the other hand, *if I were to reference the library from Google, it loads fine each and every time.*  However, external libraries are not an option; everything in the live site has to be self contained.

Intellisense is even running perfectly fine when I'm coding in the first place.

I tried `$(document).ready()`, `$(window).load()`, moving it from the master page to the .aspx page.  Nothing works, but only the first time.

Has anyone encountered something like this?  How did you solve this conundrum?

(Also, I apologize again if this is something very simple).

Edit: It's giving an object expected error when it loads.  Doing a bit of looking around it seemed to tell me that, nope, the library simply hasn't loaded yet.

Edit 2: Code:

I really should have done this before hand.  My fault.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >

function cycleImages() {
    var $active = $('#portfolio_cycler .active');
    var $next = ($('#portfolio_cycler .active').next().length > 0) ? $('#portfolio_cycler .active').next() : $('#portfolio_cycler img:first');
    $next.css('z-index', 2); //move the next image up the pile
    $active.fadeOut(1500, function () {//fade out the top image
        $active.css('z-index', 1).show().removeClass('active'); //reset the z-index and unhide the image
        $next.css('z-index', 3).addClass('active'); //make the next image the top one
    });
}    

//$(document).ready(function () { 
//    setInterval('cycleImages()', 7000);
//});

$(window).load(function () {
    setInterval('cycleImages()', 7000);
});

</script>
```

This is the jQuery method.  setInterval is the code for the fading method, but it always stops on the `$(window).load`, or `$(document).ready` it's placed in the topmost master page, in the header tag.

Comment: Is the sample above the rendered HTML? Is your scripts directory actually capitalized? Does Firebug show that the jquery library has actually loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the postback that is enabling the query reference is "logging in", then it is a permissions issue. Your application is restricting access to the .js files for only authenticated users. You need to make sure these files are accessible to anonymous users as well.

Comment: Oh for the love of...  *sigh*  Thank you, you're a lifesaver.

Comment: You might consider tools like Firebug (Javascript) or IE Developer toolbar (press F12 in IE) to troubleshoot these type of issues, as the console can tell you when certain files fail to load, etc. Won't necessarily hand you the answer, but should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding the document ready call...

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
   $(function () {

      Your code...

   });
</script>
```